# Get fire times of a trigger

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I know one can get the next fire time of a trigger by using

```
DateTimeOffset? nextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
```

But how can I get a list of all the future executions (or at least next `X` executions if it has no end) of this trigger?

Comment: Should be easy to figure out depending on the ScheduleBuilder used to create the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetFireTimeAfter(DateTimeOffSet? afterTime)` on the trigger.

```
    var nextDateTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

    //get next 1000 fire times
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       if (!nextDateTime.HasValue) break;

       Console.WriteLine(nextDateTime.Value.ToLocalTime()); 

       nextDateTime = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(nextDateTime);
    }
```